# While Debugging NodeJs getting Error as "Uncaught Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, debugging

Getting Error as "Uncaught Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND xx.xxx.x.112\ABC" while debugging NodeJs Code in Chrome Debugger.

*Below are the Server Details:*

1. Server where NodeJs Code resides: xxx.xx.x.100
2. Server where SQL is installed: xx.xxx.xx.90
3. Database Server: xx.xxx.x.112\ABC
4. Database Server Port: 51269.

*Below is my NodeJs Code:*

```js
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    debugger
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "xx.xxx.x.112\ABC",
    user: "sa",
    password: "Pass",
    port:51269
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) 
    throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    });
```

Below is the Error Details:

```js
VM52 trial2.js:11 Uncaught Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND xx.xxx.x.112\ABC
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (E:\pradeep\Node\SQL_Example\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (E:\pradeep\Node\SQL_Example\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (E:\pradeep\Node\SQL_Example\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\pradeep\Node\SQL_Example\trial2.js:10:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:773:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:839:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

The Error Message is

```js
function dnsException(code, syscall, hostname)
```

Also check the below screenshot where Error Message is returning from:
[image]

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated, as I am new to NodeJs and scratching my head since last 2-days regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below code its working for me so.

Or try with removing port and as you already providing the host server.

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');
    debugger
    var con = mysql.createConnection(config:{
    host: "host_for_connection",
    user: "user_name",
    password: "paaword",
    port: your_portNumber
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) 
    throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nilesh for your help, tried the Shared code but getting new Error messsage now as "Uncaught Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306".

Tried by both with & without Port.

**Note**: Nodejs code is in other Machine and Sql is installed in another Machine

Below is the NodeJs Code:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
debugger
var con = mysql.createConnection({
        config:{
            host: "xx.xxx.x.112\ABC",
            user: "sa",
            password: "Pass",
           // port:51269
        }
    });
     
con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) 
      throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Below is the Error Message:

```js
VM52 trial2.js:15 Uncaught Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (E:\pradeep\Node\SQL_Example\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (E:\pradeep\Node\SQL_Example\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (E:\pradeep\Node\SQL_Example\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\pradeep\Node\SQL_Example\trial2.js:12:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:773:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:839:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
exceptionWithHostPort @ VM9 errors.js:512
afterConnect @ VM81 net.js:1056
TickObject (async)
init @ VM43 inspector_async_hook.js:21
emitInitNative @ VM21 async_hooks.js:134
emitInitScript @ VM21 async_hooks.js:341
TickObject @ VM22 task_queues.js:102
nextTick @ VM22 task_queues.js:130
(anonymous) @ VM72 destroy.js:43
Socket._destroy @ VM81 net.js:595
destroy @ VM72 destroy.js:37
afterConnect @ VM81 net.js:1065
TCPCONNECTWRAP (async)
init @ VM43 inspector_async_hook.js:21
emitInitNative @ VM21 async_hooks.js:134
internalConnect @ VM81 net.js:816
defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope @ VM21 async_hooks.js:301
emitLookup @ VM81 net.js:978
onlookup @ VM156 dns.js:65
GETADDRINFOREQWRAP (async)
init @ VM43 inspector_async_hook.js:21
emitInitNative @ VM21 async_hooks.js:134
lookup @ VM156 dns.js:145
(anonymous) @ VM81 net.js:958
defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope @ VM21 async_hooks.js:301
lookupAndConnect @ VM81 net.js:957
Socket.connect @ VM81 net.js:891
connect @ VM81 net.js:168
connect @ VM55 Connection.js:76
(anonymous) @ VM52 trial2.js:12
Module._compile @ VM44 loader.js:773
Module._extensions..js @ VM44 loader.js:787
Module.load @ VM44 loader.js:643
Module._load @ VM44 loader.js:556
Module.runMain @ VM44 loader.js:839
(anonymous) @ VM40 run_main_module.js:17
```